How to use cached data in a different component using useLazyQuery in RTK Query?
I am using useLazyQuery and a trigger function to trigger an API call from a component(let's say A) but in another component(let's say B) I just want to subscribe to the cached data, I don't want to use the trigger function because component(B) will not have the exact parameters that is use by the trigger function in component(A)
I don't want to make an API call from component(B) but only display the cached data how can I do it?

This question is similar to: useLazyQuery doesn't update data between all components. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
